# Unable to run perforce commands via jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have one script `test_run.py` that internally runs few perforce/p4 commands. So in order to run perforce commands 1st we need to authenticate to perforce. So i have created p4 credentials named
:`p4_creds` with my login credentials In Jenkins

```
 stage('Run script'){
          withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'p4_creds', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'P4PASSWD')]){
                   sh '''
                       export P4USER=${USERNAME}
                       export P4PASSWD=${P4PASSWD}
                       export P4CLIENT=${jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}}
                       chmod +x test_run.py
                       python2 test_run.py 
                   '''
                }         
}
```

When i try to run the job, It fails with `Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.` , I am following this :- https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-58209 to setup my pipeline. Am i missing something?

Comment: You should make sure:
- you do not have wrong password set in Jenkins
- you do read variable inside Python script properly
- you authenticate inside Python script in the right way

Comment: @grzegorzgrzegorz, Seems like password is not retrieving correctly to jenkins pipeline job. My password is `Hello$#12`  but in pipeline it takes `Hello012` why is it happening ? I am sure that i set correctly in Configure credentials. Does pipeline wont accepts special characters ?

Comment: It is interpolating `$#` as `0` for some reason. For sure it will happen when you use double quotes:
`sh "export P4USER=${USERNAME}"`
Are you using single quotes? What is the retrieval process of environment variable inside python script ?

Comment: Somehow i am able to fix it by using singe quotes ''' and whole `sh '''` is enclosed in `environement { sh '''' .... '''' }`